# How to run a C++ program compiled with MinGW in Eclipse? How to "link(?)"?

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

before I start: sorry for my lack of english, I hope you can help me anyway, I'm a beginner.

I have the following problem. I want to run a C++ program in Eclipse which uses the boost library and other librarys. I use the MinGW Compiler, but when I try to debug / run the program I get this Error:

cannot find -lC:\Users*myusername*\Desktop\git\include
cannot find -lC:\Users*myusername*\Desktop\git\include\boost

I included the libraries in the following way: Project -> Properties -> C++ General -> Path and Symbols -> Libraries -> Here I added those 2 folders (include and boost). 
In Library Paths I just included the "include" folder. 
I also included "include" in the includes-tab.

I also made changes here: Project -> Properties -> C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings. I filled the 2 fields (-l and -L) with both "include" and "boost".

I have no clue what I could do to fix this. Do I have to add both the include and the boost folder? The reason why I ask this is because the boost folder is in the include folder (as you can see in the error-text).

My question is now: How can I avoid/fix those mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "Libraries" tab you must specify only libraries names, like "boost" in your case, not the folders. In Library Paths add full paths to every library, specified at "Libraries" tab, so compiler could find it. On the "Includes" tab you have to specify paths to your folders with program headers, i suppose adding "C:\Users*yourusername*\Desktop\git\include" will work good.
And after that you don't have to manually fill fields at Tool Settings screen, you did it already on another tabs.

---

Added:
By the look of your error i can suggest that you added full paths to folders at "Libraries" tab, not the libraries names. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it didn't work. I took a few screenshots of my settings, would be awesome if you check them out. Maybe I did something wrong. (I'm sorry if posting links isn't allowed here! Didn't find a feature to upload images!)

http://oi47.tinypic.com/339lm6w.jpg
http://oi45.tinypic.com/5557xl.jpg
http://oi50.tinypic.com/1se2kz.jpg

-> No changes were made here:
http://oi45.tinypic.com/1zohn38.jpg

Comment: Looks right. What error compiler is typing now? Check, if the boost library is really in C:\Users\nitschmann\Desktop\git\boost folder, not in C:\Users\nitschmann\Desktop\git\boost\lib for example.

Comment: Hey. I get the following error: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost. I made sure the path is correct, I still get the error. Any further tips? :/ Sorry!

Comment: It's look like there's no such library as "boost", it's separated into different libs like "boost_system", "boost_algorithm" etc, and some features don't need linking with any separated libs at all. So I think you need to find out what libs you are really using and change your libraries settings accordingly.